# How to find an element in other rows of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Could someone please help me with this problem in R. Here is the sample data I am working with:

```
df <- data.frame(item = c("x", "y", "z"),
                 code1 = c("3 9 27 45 88 98", "23", "12 45"),
                 code2 = c("45 88 98 99 102 159", "42", "27 0 99"))
df
```

and the data frame looks like this:

```
  item           code1               code2
1    x 3 9 27 45 88 98 45 88 98 99 102 159
2    y              23                  42
3    z           12 45             27 0 99
```

I would like to find each element of variable `code1` into `code2` but not in the same row. For example, observation 1 has an element 27 which is present into observation 3 so the new variable must record it as count 1. If the observation would have had more than one elements in any other observations other than the current one than the code should count them all. Similarly, observation 3 has element 45 in observation 1 so the new variable would record it as count 1. Lastly, the second observation element is not present in any other observation and hence the new variable should count 0. Here is the expected result:

```
   item           code1               code2  code3
1    x 3 9 27 45 88 98 45 88 98 99 102 159       1
2    y              23                  42       0
3    z           12 45             27 0 99       1
```

I have tried, using `which(code1 %in% code2)`, looped through the elements of code1 using for loop and searched into code2, used sapply with a function where index was one less than the current one but none of these try are fruitful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `%in%` directly since `%in%` looks for exact match in `code1` and `code2`, whereas what you need is to check for each number individually. You can split `code1` and `code2` on whitespace, iterate over their index, for each index in `lst1` remove the corresponding values from `lst2` and count the common values using `%in%`.

```
lst1 <- strsplit(df$code1, '\\s+')
lst2 <- strsplit(df$code2, '\\s+')
df$code3 <- sapply(seq_along(lst1), function(x) 
                   sum(lst1[[x]] %in% unlist(lst2[-x])))

df
#  item           code1               code2 code3
#1    x 3 9 27 45 88 98 45 88 98 99 102 159     1
#2    y              23                  42     0
#3    z           12 45             27 0 99     1
```

If you are using R < 4.0.0 your columns would be factors, change them to characters by doing:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(item = c("x", "y", "z"),
                 code1 = c("3 9 27 45 88 98", "23", "12 45"),
                 code2 = c("45 88 98 99 102 159", "42", "27 0 99"))

df1 <- df %>%
  select("item1" = item, code1) %>%
  mutate(code1 = str_split(code1, pattern = " ")) %>%
  unnest

df2 <- df %>%
  select("item2" = item, code2) %>%
  mutate(code2 = str_split(code2, pattern = " ")) %>%
  unnest

df3 <- crossing(df1, df2) %>%
  filter(item1 != item2) %>%
  mutate(code3 = code1 == code2) %>%
  select("item" = item1, code3) %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  summarise(code3 = sum(code3)) %>% ungroup()

df_out <- inner_join(df, df3)
```